# Is the sum of one-particle-irreducivle two-point diagrams always a real number?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, propagator, 1pi-effective-action

On page 388 in section 11.6 of Peskin and Shroeder.
There appears an equation of the inverse propagator(the second functional derivative of the effective action) for a theory that contains several scalar fields:
$$ K^2_{ij} =: \int d^4x e ^{ip\cdot (x-y)}\frac{\delta^2 \Gamma}{\delta \phi^i\delta \phi^j}(x,y)=0  \tag{11.105} $$
When diagonalizing
$$ K^2_{ij} = P_{ik}P_{jl}\tilde{K}^2_{kl} = (P\tilde{K}P^t)_{ij} \, , \quad P \,\text{:an orthogonal matrix} $$
the property that $K^2_{ij}\,$: real is needed.
After diagonalizing
$$ \tilde{K}^2_{ii}=p^2-m_{i0}^2-M_i^2(p^2) \quad\quad\text{i : no sum} \, ,$$
where $m_{i0}$ is the bare mass of the $i$th scalar field and $M_i^2(p^2)$ is the sum of one-particle-irreducivle two-point diagrams.
Is $M_i^2(p^2)$ always a real number?
That's simply because
$$ \tilde{K}^2_{ii}=0 \quad \Leftrightarrow \quad m_i^2=m_{i0}^2-M_i^2(m_i^2) \quad ? $$
,where $m_i$ is the physical mass.
Is that whole the story? Is there some other reason?
Thanks.

Comment: Note that $M^2(p^2)$ may acquire a non-zero imaginary part at the threshold of  pair production (branch cut) if the model has unstable particles.

Comment: @AccidentalFourierTransform Would you please also comment on Adam's answer, which points out that the effective potential is always real from the viewpoint of path integral after the Wick rotation.

Answer (score 2):

The matrix $K_{ij}$ define by the OP is just the second derivative of the effective potential (see [A question about the proof of Goldstone's theorem](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/306046/a-question-about-the-proof-of-goldstones-theorem/352298#352298) ). The effective potential being a real function of the fields. Indeed, it is the Legendre transform of the log of the  generating functional, which, after Wick rotation (and using notations of quantum statistical physics), is defined as
$$Z=\langle e^{-\beta (\hat H+J_i \int_x\hat \phi_i(x))} \rangle,$$
where the Hamiltonian in presence of (constant) sources is hermitian. This implies that $Z$ is real (by just diagonalizing the Hamiltonian), and therefore so is the effective potential.

Its second derivative, evaluated at its minimum, is therefore a real symmetric matrix, which can be diagonalized, with positive (or zero) eigenvalues.

Without Wick rotation, the effective potential might be purely imaginary depending on its definition, but this does not change the argument.

Comment: Concerning AccidentalFourierTransform's comments above, so Z is not necessarily real? But it is necessary in the sense that mass must be non-negative definite. Can you give more comments?

Comment: @gamebm : AccidentalFourierTransform's comments is about the fact that some propagators might have poles in the complex plane (and not just on the real line), due to decay from a particle into another kind of particle. But this happens after Wick rotation, and does not change the fact that one can diagonalize the matrix $K$.

Comment: I still do not understand. The second order derivative of $\Gamma$ is related to the inverse propagator (Eqs.(11.90) & (11.92) on the textbook), namely, $p^2-m^2-M^2(p^2)$. If the mass pole is in the complex plane, the $M^2$ part of the expression is not real. According to your derivation, $Z$, $\Gamma$, and hence the second derivatives of the effective potential are real. So I stuck there, the second derivative should be real or not? I know that I obviously missed something. Would you please be more specific on the "after the Wick rotation" part, many thanks!

Comment: @gamebm: $x^2+1$ is real, yet its zeros are imaginary... although it might be too simple an example, that might help you.

Comment: thx for the answer! I see you point. But for this particular question, is it literally the case? For resonance states, according to the textbook (around P.235, when two propagators simultaneously go on-shell), $M^2$ indeed possess non-vanishing real as well as imaginary parts. How does this fit in the context? Thanks in advance for the further explanations.

Comment: do you have the precise page / equation ?

Comment: P.237 (7.58), the expression below it and (7.61). The discussions start on P.232 about the "optical theorem" in the calculations of Feynman diagram (2 point iPT is a particular case). It states that when it is possible for two propagators to go on-shell simultaneously (related to a cut which goes through two internal lines), there is an additional $i$ factor, which possibly gives rise to the imaginary part. Then it deals with the case of "unstable particle" as an example. The real part of $M^2$ goes to the mass correction, while the imaginary part contributes to the half-life.

Comment: @gamebm : this happens because $p$ has a small imaginary part $i\epsilon$, to obtain a retarded propagator. But as long as you are working in euclidian space-time (where everything is well defined), the self-energy is real (up to trivial factors coming from the definitions of the potential, etc.)

Comment: I am not sure I understand, the small imaginary part in mass is always there even for stable particles, here the book is discussion resonance, and the Feynman rules which leads to a finite imaginary contribution. The calculations there show explicitly how it happens, this is when one is able to cut two propagators simultaneously, please be specific how it can be understood in terms of integral in Euclidean space. My apologies for the ignorance.

Comment: In euclidean space-time, all diagrams are real (up to trivial factors depending of definitions, etc.). Therefore, there is no imaginary part. When one is interested in real time (for instance, the decay of a particle), one needs to analytically continue the propagators, using $ip_0\to p_0+i\epsilon$, this is how a finite imaginary part can appear. See arxiv:1108.5207 section IV for an explicit calculation + analytic continuation.

Comment: Really appreciated for the comments! I understand that $Z$ in Euclidean space is real, since the path integral is equivalent to the partition function which is positive definite. However, my doubt is from a different viewpoint, according to the comments of AccidentalFourierTransform, which involves the explicit calculation of self-energy correction, and the imaginary part is not infinitesimal, but finite, the former implies a stable particle, the latter corresponds to a resonance state with finite life-time. Can you comment explicitly on this and their relationship?

Comment: @gamebm : yes, the imaginary part can be finite, but this is so only when you are in minkowski space-time. If it is still unclear, I would suggest that you ask a new question. That would be easier to answer than in the comments here.

Comment: done, I posted a new question, thx!

Comment: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/358329/about-the-calculation-of-one-particle-irreducible-two-point-diagram