# Issue with understanding the Weinberg's proof of the Goldstone boson theorem

Tags: quantum-field-theory, conventions, symmetry-breaking, goldstone-mode

To prove Goldstone's theorem Weinberg (in volume II, page 170, equation 19.2.18) starts with the expectation value over the vacuum of the commutator between one field $\phi_n(x)$ and the conserved current associated with the symmetry $J^{\lambda}(y)$, he writes:

> Summing over intermediate states this is:
> $$ \left<[J^{\lambda}(y),\phi_n(x)]\right>_{VAC} = (2\pi)^{-3} \int d^4 p [\rho^{\lambda}_n(p)e^{ip(x-y)} - \tilde{\rho}^{\lambda}_n(p)e^{ip(x-y)}].\tag{19.2.18}
> $$

I would have written the same formula with a $(2\pi)^{-4}$ instead of a $(2\pi)^{-3}$ my understanding being that the $p$ exponential term and $2\pi$ come from Fourier transforming the left side and thus I would expect a $2\pi$ for each of the coordinates. What am I doing wrong?
Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$
\langle \Omega|[J^\mu(y),\phi_n(x)]|\Omega\rangle=\langle \Omega|J^\mu(y)\phi_n(x)-\phi_n(x)J^\mu(y)|\Omega\rangle
\\=\int d\Pi\ \langle\Omega|J^\mu(y)|p,\lambda\rangle \langle p,\lambda|\phi_n(x)|\Omega\rangle-\langle\Omega|\phi_n(x)|p,\lambda\rangle \langle p,\lambda|J^\mu(y)|\Omega\rangle
\\d\Pi=\frac{d^3 p}{(2\pi)^3}\frac{1}{2E_p(\lambda)}
$$
where the integral is also formally over all intermediate single-particle and multi-particle states, which ensures that $\int d\Pi\ |p,\lambda\rangle\langle p,\lambda|$ obeys the completeness relation. This has the proper normalisation for a completeness relation (which you might recognise as a simple extrapolation of the integration measure for the scalar field mode expansion), and is equivalent to the Lorentz-invariant phase space up to the momentum-conserving delta function and factors of $2\pi$. Now, translating to the origin:
$$
=\int d\Pi\ \langle\Omega|J^\mu(0)|p,\lambda\rangle \langle p,\lambda|\phi_n(0)|\Omega\rangle e^{ip(x-y)}-\langle\Omega|\phi_n(0)|p,\lambda\rangle \langle p,\lambda|J^\mu(0)|\Omega\rangle e^{-ip(x-y)}
$$
Consider only the first term for simplicity:
$$
\int d\Pi\ \langle\Omega|J^\mu(0)|p,\lambda\rangle \langle p,\lambda|\phi_n(0)|\Omega\rangle e^{ip(x-y)}
\\=\int \frac{d^4 p}{(2\pi)^4}e^{ip(x-y)}\int d\Pi\ (2\pi)^4\delta(p-\tilde p)\langle\Omega|J^\mu(0)|p,\lambda\rangle \langle p,\lambda|\phi_n(0)|\Omega\rangle
$$
where $\tilde p$ is the four-momentum of the current intermediate state in the sum.
$$
2\pi\rho_+^\mu(p)\equiv\int d\Pi\ (2\pi)^4\delta(p-\tilde p)\langle\Omega|J^\mu(0)|p,\lambda\rangle \langle p,\lambda|\phi_n(0)|\Omega\rangle
\\\Rightarrow \langle \Omega|[J^\mu(y),\phi_n(x)]|\Omega\rangle = \int \frac{d^4 p}{(2\pi)^3} \left(\rho_+^\mu(p)e^{ip(x-y)}-\rho_-^\mu(p)e^{-ip(x-y)}\right)
$$
Alternatively, the insertion of the complete set of states brings $d^3p/(2\pi)^3$, and in converting to the spectral representation $\rho_\pm^\mu(m^2)$ which has a delta function $\delta(m^2-\tilde m^2)$ (as all intermediate states in the Hilbert-space are on-shell. Even the spectral density for multiparticle states contains the delta function, although $\rho(m^2)$ is not "spiked" for them), we must add a $\int d(m^2)$ while integrating over *all* states, which turns the integration measure into $d^4p/(2\pi)^3$.

Comment: Thank you very much!